# Selenium WebDriver Java identify form input button

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I have a button with html:

```
<form action="home.php">
  <input type="submit" value="Continue">
</form>
```

In my Java code I have:

```
driver.findElement(By.);
```

How do I select the button to click/submit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could do it I think:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type=submit]")).click();
```

Comment: That would do it! Thank you!

Comment: @IanD This answer contains a CSS Selector. In order to understand how it works and how to create the next one you will need, you can refer to this [CSS Selector reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors).